# Haskell TimeZone value from time zone identifier

Tags: haskell, timezone

How does one get from a time zone identifier such as `"Europe/Berlin"` to a [`TimeZone`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.8.0.1/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#t:TimeZone) value? I imagine a function with a type such as `Text -> Maybe TimeZone`, but haven't yet found one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Data.Time.LocalTime.TimeZone.Olson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/timezone-olson-0.1.7/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime-TimeZone-Olson.html) allows for reading time zone specification files and offers [TimeZoneSeries](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/timezone-series-0.1.5.1/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime-TimeZone-Series.html#t:TimeZoneSeries) values which encapsulates the various oddities of time zones and Daylight Saving Time.

Time Zones are complex, so you can't completely infer a `TimeZone` from an identifier like `"Europe/Berlin"` without giving it an actual UTC time from which to work. That's what `TimeZoneSeries` solves, with a number of conversion functions.

Comment: Well, one can get a time zone from an identifier, but a specific offset requires a point in time. There's some confusion in Haskell because these libraries aren't using common terminology.  `TimeZone` the way it's defined in the Haskell `time` package is just a named offset - not a time zone in the sense of "Pacific Time" or "Central European Time".  Basically, see "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and recognize that Haskell has different definitions of terminology.  (+1 for the reference to the `timezone-olson` package)

Comment: Cue Tom Scott’s video about time zones.
TL;DW: It’s a nightmare. There’s always one intricacy or exception that’s missed.
Hence all the confusion and problems mentioned here.